# How generate a family of polynomials in fortran

Tags: fortran, recurrence, polynomials

I have a following recurrence relation for a given polynomial

**P**<sub>n</sub>(**x**) = **P**<sub>n-1</sub>(**x**) - **x** * **P**<sub>n-3</sub>(**x**), with n>=1.

with initial condition **P**<sub>-2</sub>(**x**) = **P**<sub>-1</sub>(**x**) = **P**<sub>0</sub>(**x**) = 1.

I try to write a subroutine in Fortran that calculate the coefficients of this polynomial. My source code is given by

```
integer,parameter::lmax = 10

real*8  A(1:lmax)
real*8  B(1:lmax,1:lmax)
integer n,k

   print *,' '
   do n = 4, lmax
     write(*,25) n

     call polynomial_coeff(n,A,B)

     do k = 1, n-1  
       write(*,50) k, A(k)  
     end do 
     print *,' '
     if (n<lmax) pause ' <Enter> to continue...'
   end do
   print *,' '

   stop
25 format(' polynomial coefficients for order',i2/)
50 format('   A(',i2,') = ',f10.0)

end

!**************************************************
!* polynomial coefficients evaluation by          *
!* means of recursion relation. The order of the  *
!* polynomial is n. The coefficients are returned *
!* in A(i).                                       *
!**************************************************
Subroutine polynomial_coeff(n,A,B)  
  integer,parameter::lmax = 10
  integer i,j
  real*8  A(1:lmax), B(1:lmax,1:lmax)
  
  !Establish initial coefficients
  B(1,1)=1.d0 ; B(1,2)=-1.d0 ; B(1,3)=0.d0; 
  B(2,1) = 1.0d0; B(2,2) = -2.0d0; B(2,3) = 0.0d0;
  B(3,1) = 1.0d0; B(3,2) = -3.0d0; B(3,3) = 0.0d0
  
  !Return if order is less than two
  if (n>3) then
    do i = 4, n
      B(i,1)=1.d0*B(i-1,1)
      do j = 1, i-2
        !Basic recursion relation
        B(i,j)=1.d0*B(i-1,j)-1.d0*B(i-3,j)
      end do
    end do
    do i = 1, n-1
      A(i)=B(n,i)
    end do
  end if
  return
end
```

The five initial polynomials are given by:

P_{1}(x) = 1 - x

P_{2}(x) = 1 - 2x

P_{3}(x) = 1 - 3x

P_{4}(x) = 1 - 4x + x²

P_{5}(x) = 1 - 5x + 3x².

But i have the following results for the coefficients of the 4-th and 5-th polynomial:

```
 polynomial coefficients for order 4

   A( 1) =         0.
   A( 2) =        -2.
   A( 3) =         0.
```

instead of A(1) = 1, A(2) = -4 and A(3) = 1. And

```
 polynomial coefficients for order 5

   A( 1) =        -1.
   A( 2) =         0.
   A( 3) =         0.
   A( 4) =         0.
```

Instead of A(1) = 1, A(2) = -5, A(3) = 3.

I'm grateful for anyone who can help me.

Comment: After a quick read, is seems that you do not account for the factor `x *`.

Comment: There is an issue because `P_3` calls `P_0` which is not defined. Maybe there is a typo in the question.

Comment: The initial condition has `P_2(x) = 1` but the output states `P_2(x) = 1-2x` which one is it?

Comment: The initial conditions are really incorrect. The five polynomials showed above are produced if we consider P_{-2} = P{-1} = P_{0} = 1.

Answer (score 4):

The information given isn't consistent. The initial conditions do not result in the expected polynomials. Also the recursion contains a reference to `P_{n-3}(x)` which is undefined for `n=3`. So I assumed it is a typo and the recursion is `P_{n} = P_{n-1} - x * P_{n-2}`.

---

Working with a CAS system I found the following polynomial iterations

[image: fig1]

which do not match the value you expect in the question.

Besides that, I can replicate the polynomials above with the following `Fortran` program. First the result, showing the iteration of polynomials.

```text
    iter P_{n} = P_{n-1} - x*P_{n-2}
       1 (1.000)
       2 (1.000)
       3 (1.000) + (-1.000)*x
       4 (1.000) + (-2.000)*x
       5 (1.000) + (-3.000)*x + (1.000)*x^2
       6 (1.000) + (-4.000)*x + (3.000)*x^2
       7 (1.000) + (-5.000)*x + (6.000)*x^2 + (-1.000)*x^3
       8 (1.000) + (-6.000)*x + (10.00)*x^2 + (-4.000)*x^3
```

using the following test code below.

#### PROGRAM

I decided to define a user-type called `polynomial` in order to do the algebra, and displaying like modern pseudo-OOP Fortran can.

```
program FortranConsolePolynomial
use mod_polynomial
implicit none

! Variables
type(polynomial) ::  p
integer :: i

! Body of FortranConsolePolynomial

write(*, '(a8,1x,a)') 'iter', 'P_{n} = P_{n-1} - x*P_{n-2}'
do i=1, 8
    p = poly_iter(i)
    write(*, '(i8,1x,a)')  i, p%show()
end do    

contains

pure function poly_iter(n) result(p)
type(polynomial) :: p
integer, intent(in) :: n
type(polynomial), allocatable :: poly(:)
type(polynomial) :: x, one
integer :: i

    one = [ 1.0_wp ]
    x = [ 0.0_wp, 1.0_wp ]

    allocate(poly(max(n,2)))
    poly(1) = one 
    poly(2) = one 
            
    do i=3, n
        poly(i) = poly(i-1) - (x * poly(i-2))
    end do
    
    p = poly(n)

end function

end program
```

The resulting algebra is correct (as checked by the CAS system) because the recursion is defined with one line

```
poly(i) = poly(i-1) - (x * poly(i-2))
```

I am letting Fortran do its **FO**rmula **TRAN**slation and produce accurate results. This way I am confident that the calculation I intended to do is actually what is going on (after checking that the results are as expected).

#### POLYNOMIAL

The type `polynomial` contains an array of coefficients `coef(0:n)` and more importantly several functions that act on this type to define the algebra of polynomials. The coefficients are stored with the constant term first, then the coefficient for `x`, then `x^2` and so on.

Specifically, the operators `+`, `-`, and `*` are defined, as well as the assignment operator `=` to and from array types.

This means that given three polynomial variables `pa`, `pb`, and `pc` and an array `arr` the following are valid code

- `pa = arr` :  Define polynomial from array coefficients
- `arr = pa` :  Get coefficients from polynomial
- `pc = pa + pb` : Add two polynomials
- `pc = pa - pb` : Subtract two polynomials
- `pc = 2.0*pa` : Scale a polynomial by a factor
- `pc = pa * pb` : Multiply two polynomials

In full the polynomial type and interfaces are defined in the module below

```
module mod_polynomial
use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env
implicit none

integer, parameter :: wp = real64

type :: polynomial
    real(wp), allocatable :: coef(:)
contains
procedure :: order => p_order
procedure :: eval => p_eval_x
procedure :: show => p_to_string
end type

interface order
module procedure :: p_order
end interface

interface operator (+)
module procedure :: p_add
end interface
interface operator (-)
module procedure :: p_sub
end interface
interface operator (*)
module procedure :: p_scale1, p_scale2, p_mul
end interface

interface assignment (=)
module procedure p_from_array, array_from_p
end interface

contains

pure subroutine p_from_array(p,a)
type(polynomial), intent(out) :: p
real(wp), intent(in) :: a(:)
integer :: order
    order = size(a)-1
    allocate(p%coef(0:order))
    p%coef(0:order) = a(:)
end subroutine

pure subroutine array_from_p(a,p)
real(wp), intent(out), allocatable :: a(:)
class(polynomial), intent(in) :: p
integer :: o
    o = order(p)
    allocate(a(1:o+1))
    a(:) = p%coef(0:o)
end subroutine

pure function new_const(x) result(p)
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
type(polynomial) :: p
    allocate(p%coef(0:0))
    p%coef(0) = x
end function

pure function p_order(p) result(n)
integer :: n
class(polynomial), intent(in) :: p
    n = size(p%coef)-1
end function

pure function p_eval_x(p,x) result(y)
class(polynomial), intent(in) :: p
real(wp), intent(in) :: x
real(wp):: y
integer :: i, order
order = size(p%coef)-1
y = 0.0_wp
do i=0, order
    y = x*y + p%coef(order-i)
end do
end function

pure function p_to_string(p,fmt) result(polystr)
class(polynomial), intent(in) :: p
character(len=*), intent(in), optional :: fmt
!real(wp), intent(in) :: p%coef(0:)
character(len=:), allocatable :: polystr, buffer
character(32) :: s
integer :: i

if(present(fmt)) then
    buffer = fmt
else
    buffer = "g0.4"
end if

write(s,'("(",' // trim(buffer) // ',")")') p%coef(0)
polystr = trim(s)

do i = 1, ubound(p%coef,1)
    !write(s,'("(",g0.4,")")') p%coef(i)
    write(s,'("(",' // trim(buffer) // ',")")') p%coef(i)
    if (i == 1) then
        s = trim(s) // '*x'
    else if (i > 1) then
        s = trim(s) // '*x^' // achar(iachar('0') + i)
    end if
    polystr = polystr // ' + ' // trim(s)
end do
end function

! Algebra

pure function p_add(a,b) result(c)
type(polynomial), intent(in) :: a,b
type(polynomial) :: c
integer :: na, nb, nc
    na = order(a)
    nb = order(b)
    nc = max(na,nb)
    allocate(c%coef(0:nc))
    c%coef = 0.0_wp
    c%coef(0:na) = a%coef(0:na)
    c%coef(0:nb) = c%coef(0:nb) + b%coef(0:nb)
end function
pure function p_sub(a,b) result(c)
type(polynomial), intent(in) :: a,b
type(polynomial) :: c
integer :: na, nb, nc
    na = order(a)
    nb = order(b)
    nc = max(na,nb)
    allocate(c%coef(0:nc))
    c%coef = 0.0_wp
    c%coef(0:na) = a%coef(0:na)        
    c%coef(0:nb) = c%coef(0:nb) - b%coef(0:nb)
end function
pure function p_scale1(a,b) result(c)
real(wp), intent(in) :: a
type(polynomial), intent(in) :: b
type(polynomial) :: c
integer :: nc
    nc = order(b)
    allocate(c%coef(0:nc))
    c%coef(0:nc) = a * b%coef(0:nc)
end function
pure function p_scale2(b,a) result(c)
real(wp), intent(in) :: a
type(polynomial), intent(in) :: b
type(polynomial) :: c
integer :: nc
    nc = order(b)
    allocate(c%coef(0:nc))
    c%coef(0:nc) = a * b%coef(0:nc)
end function

pure function p_mul(a,b) result(c)
type(polynomial), intent(in) :: a, b
type(polynomial) :: c
integer :: na, nb, nc
integer :: i,j,k
    na = order(a)
    nb = order(b)
    nc = na + nb
    allocate(c%coef(0:nc))
    c%coef = 0.0_wp
    do i=0, na
        do j=0, nb
            k = i + j
            c%coef(k) = c%coef(k) + a%coef(i)*b%coef(j)
        end do
    end do
end function

end module
```

Equation form for the polynomial using the `p_to_string()` function.

Comment: Made an update on the post adding some more details.